# UserControl DirectMethod Not firing in Ext.net

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

> HI, I am Loading one UserControl(Which has the GridPanel in it ) into
>   tabPanel.
>
> But when i click on Gridpanel Edit Command Button the Event at Server
>   side method not working and showing the Exception like
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The control with ID
>   'id8b177c82adb2e925' not found.
>
> My Code here is
>
> For the userControl : the .ascx code is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GridPanelUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Ext_PracticeExamples.GridPanelUserControl" %>


<ext:GridPanel ID="gpEmployeeList" runat="server" StripeRows="true" Title="Employee List" Layout="FitLayout"
    Width="620" Height="400" AutoExpandColumn="FirstName">

    <Store>
       .....  
    </Store>
    <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
        <Columns>

              <ext:ImageCommandColumn ID="imgSettings"    runat="server" Text="Settings" Resizable="false">
                <Commands>
                    <ext:ImageCommand Icon="BasketEdit" Style="text-align: center" CommandName="Settings">
                    </ext:ImageCommand>
                </Commands>
                <Listeners>
                    <Command Handler=" #{DirectMethods}.fnDisplaySettings(record.data.Company,record.data.Price,record.data.Change);" />

                </Listeners>
            </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
```

> and the Corresponding .cs Class file method which is not firing.

```
  [DirectMethod]
     public void fnDisplaySettings(string name, double X, double Y)
     {     
      // ..some Operation....    
         Response.Redirect("~/_Default.aspx");
     }
```

> while Observing the Source page in webBrowser i find that the Controls have
>   different Id so that Corresponding  function not displaying.If i give
>   "ClientIdMode=static" it gives me the Unique Id problem when i load
>   the same control in the page. If i Use this code in Single page
>   without UserControl it's working fine.
>
> What should i do Invoke the server Side Method.
>
> Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you render a user control on the fly during one request and doesn't recreate it during another request, therefore Ext.NET can't find its DirectMethod, because there is no user control instance on server.

Possible solutions are:

1. Recreate a user control during each request. Here is [a related discussion on the Ext.NET forums](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?25279).
2. Setting up a DirectMethod's handler in, for example, a WebService (asmx) or an HTTP handler (ashx), and call it via URL. Such a call won't require a user control instance. Here are examples.
   http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectMethods/WebService/
   http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectEvents/WebService/

The disadvantage of this approach is the fact that you won't be able to access a user control's controls in a WebService or an HTTP handler. All required things should be submitted from a page as extra parameters of a request.

1. Placing a DirectMethod to the page.

Comment: I decide to use second approach,but I t seems to me little bit diffucult manupulate gridvies,store, inside webservice (reaching the usercontrol elements like inside the usercontrol seems a problem) and turn to back client side,
3. approach seems me that put all those codes in a single page ,make the code readibiltiy diffucult.my question is whats your personel experiance and advises to me(I am sorry my bad english.)

Comment: **Iam also searcing which one is the best approach for my project but cant decide yet.In my project ,I have one main page,and 17-18 usercontrol available(contains button gridview and so on..),when clicking the buttons inside main page ,I load user control dynamically(also inside the this user control,calling another user control).

Comment: Yes, you cannot access a user control's controls in a WebService. All the required things should be submitted from a page as extra parameters of a request. I have edited the answer with this info. Regarding my personal preference. I prefer not to recreate user controls and use WebServices or HTTP handlers. Ideally, I would prefer to use MVC.

Comment: for the first approach(Recreate a user control during each request. ),is it available a sample on example web page.tahnk you for answer

Comment: I asked it as I am not good at web services,for example response tag return a buch of the script tag after post(for example,creat a new window and give a alert to user,or create a window and load user control),is there a way to handle this buch of the code and excutes in client side,

Comment: I think these new questions are going out of the initial topic. It would be good to create a new question.